# How to write excel formulas into cells using Python?

Tags: python-2.7

While writing excel formulas into cells using python code, after exporting I am able to see only the formulas  unless I double click on that cell and then somewhere outside the cell. How can I see the values of the formulas without manually double clicking on the cells?

**EDIT:**

The code is:

```
sheet9.write(15,6,xlwt.Formula('COUNTIF(SAC_STORE_DATA!$E:$E,RM_DM_Dashboard!$E$‌​16)'))
```

I even tried using semicolon instead of comma after `$E:$E`, but its not working.